# Ошибка tkinter, при использовании gif анимации в python. ("after" script)

Tags: python, tkinter, gif

```
from tkinter import *

import time

import os

root = Tk()

frameCnt0 = 12

frames = [PhotoImage(file='C:\\Python\\1.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(frameCnt0)]

def update(ind):

    frame = frames[ind]
    ind += 1
    if ind == frameCnt0:
        ind = 0
    label.configure(image=frame)
    root.after(100, update, ind)

label = Label(root)

label.pack()

root.after(0, update, 0)

root.mainloop()


root1 = Tk()

frameCnt1 = 12

frames = [PhotoImage(file='C:\\Python\\2.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(frameCnt1)]

def update(ind):

    frame = frames[ind]
    ind += 1
    if ind == frameCnt1:
        ind = 0
    label.configure(image=frame)
    root1.after(100, update, ind)

label = Label(root1)

label.pack()

root1.after(0, update, 0)

root1.mainloop()



root2 = Tk()

frameCnt2 = 12

frames = [PhotoImage(file='C:\\Python\\3.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(frameCnt2)]

def update(ind):

    frame = frames[ind]
    ind += 1
    if ind == frameCnt2:
        ind = 0
    label.configure(image=frame)
    root2.after(100, update, ind)

label = Label(root2)

label.pack()

root2.after(0, update, 0)

root2.mainloop()
```

выводит в консоль

```
invalid command name "17167785update
While executing 
("after script")
# invalid command name "26373832update
While executing 
26373832update
("after script")
```

Comment: А зачем вы трижды создаёте экземпляры Tk и трижды запускаете mainloop и завершаете его? Программы на tkinter не делают это более одного раза. Но если уж по какой-то причине так надо, то отменяйте все запланированные after прежде чем завершать mainloop.

Comment: Объект Tk должен быть один. Если вам нужно несколько окон закрывать/открывать, первоначальное окно Tk скрывайте, окна делайте через Toplevel

Comment: Больше спасибо, всё пофиксил)))