# Почему не отображается .gif изображение?

Tags: python, tkinter

Открывается новое окно, но картинки в нём нету.

Должна открываться картинка при наборе 777
[image: Вот эта гифка]

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import PhotoImage, Label, Tk

g=1

def dobav(a):
    global du, g

    if a == 1:
        g=g+10
    elif a==2:
        g+=100
    else:
        g=g+1

    if g == 10:
        duu=Button(window, text='10', font=("Arial Bold", 20) , command=lambda: dobav(1))
        duu.grid(column=1, row=0)
    
    if g > 100:
        duuu=Button(window, text='100', font=("Arial Bold", 20) , command=lambda: dobav(2))
        duuu.grid(column=2, row=0)

    if g==777:
        root = Tk()
        label = Label(root, image=img)
        label.pack()
        root.mainloop()

    obekt.config(text=g)



window= Tk()
window.geometry('600x600')
window.title("окно")

obekt = Label(window, text=1, font=("Arial Bold", 20))
obekt.grid(column=1, row=1)

du=Button (window, text=g, font=("Arial Bold", 20), command=lambda: dobav(0) )
du.grid(column=0, row=0)

img = PhotoImage(file="lucky-clover-four-leaf-clover.gif")

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Вот тут вроде бы рабочий пример кода с анимированным gif (не проверял), только код нужно взять до первого mailoop включительно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1367265/1365